# Using MemoryLayout on a struct gives the incorrect size

Tags: swift, struct, memory-layout

Memory layout behaves a little strange when trying to find the size of a struct.

I can just maintain a function that adds the size of each. But I was wondering if there was a better way.

```
enum Mode: UInt8 {
    case tings
}

// this should be 5 - UInt8 + UInt16 + UInt16
struct Stuff {
    let mode: Mode
    let sessionID: UInt16
    let sessionCount: UInt16
}
print(MemoryLayout<Stuff>.size)                 // 4 ???
print(MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size)                // 2
print(MemoryLayout<Mode>.size)                  // 0 !?!?!?!?
print(MemoryLayout<Mode.RawValue>.size)         // 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rely on simply adding together the sizes of the individual fields of a structure to get the struct's size.

Swift can add padding into the fields of a struct to align fields on various byte boundaries to improve the efficiency in accessing the data at runtime.

If you want to allocate one item, you can simply use the `size` of the memory layout.  If you want a contiguous block of n instances then you should allocate blocks based on the `stride` of the layout.

Comment: I can accept byte alignment would make the size bigger. But do you have any idea what optimization would make the size smaller?

Comment: FYI: adding cases bumps up the size to 6.

Comment: There was only ever one value that `Mode` could have, so there was no point in storing it at all.  When you added a second case then it expanded to the `UInt8` and probably padded it out.

Comment: Right. So why did it make it 6 bytes when I added more cases? Byte alignment?

Comment: That is my guess (that's what I meant by "probably padded it out").

Comment: I know it's not discouraged as a comment, but thank you for all the info.